# Knockoutjs - Add to nested collection not updating UI

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a view model which has several layers of nested observableArrays.

```
ViewModel
    - Dictionaries[vmDictionary]
        - Concepts[vmConcept]
            - TermGroups[vmTermGroup]
                - Language
                - Terms[vmTerm]
```

I now wish to add an instance of vmTerm (the view model for a Term object) to a specific instance of vmTermGroup, and have the UI update automatically.

To achieve this I've built a function which returns the specific vmDictionary object:

```
function vmDictionaries(dicts) {

    // other JS removed for brevity

    self.Dictionaries = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Get = function (id) {
        for (var d = 0; d < self.Dictionaries().length; d++) {
            if (self.Dictionaries()[d].ID() == id) {
                return self.Dictionaries()[d];
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Once I have the specific vmDictionary object I need to obtain the specific vmConcept object which is parent to the vmTermGroup that I'm going to add to. I have an ID for this vmConcept which I can use to retrieve it:

```
var concept;
for (var c = 0; c < dict.Concepts().length; c++) {
    if (dict.Concepts()[c].ID() == conceptId) {
        concept = dict.Concepts()[c];
    }
}
```

Inside the vmConcept view model I have a function, `AddTerm`. This function figures out which vmTermGroup is required by checking each vmTermGroup's Language.ID property.

When the matching vmTermGroup is obtained, the function `push`es the new vmTerm to that vmTermGroup's Terms observableArray.

```
function vmConcept(concept) {

    // other JS removed for brevity

    self.TermGroups = ko.observableArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < concept.TermGroups.length; i++) {
        self.TermGroups.push(new vmTermGroup(concept.TermGroups[i]));
    }

    self.AddTerm = function (vmTerm) {
        // loop through all the TermGroups
        for (var i = 0; i < self.TermGroups().length; i++) {
            // if this TermGroup.Language matches the vmTerm.Language...
            if (self.TermGroups()[i].Language.ID() == vmTerm.Language.ID) {
                // ...then add vmTerm to this TermGroup
                self.TermGroups()[i].Terms.push(vmTerm);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }.bind(this);
}
```

However, when I add a new instance of vmTerm to the vmConcept instance, the UI doesn't update to display it. I can console.log the number of vmTerms in the vmTermGroup both before and after the call to `AddTerm` and it shows, for example, 2 and then 3, but the view is never updated.

I've also tried including a call to `self.TermGroups()[i].Terms.valueHasMutated()` but this makes no difference.

My suspicion is that at one or more levels I'm bypassing Knockout's observable array and diving directly into the inner (native) array, which would prevent Knockout from tracking changes, but I can't see how else I can achieve what I'm looking to do here.

I appreciate that this is a rather convoluted example/question, but does anyone know how I can add a new vmTerm to this inner-inner collection?

**EDIT**: here is the view template being used.

```
<div id="concept-container" data-bind="foreach: Concepts">

    <!-- markup removed for brevity -->

    <div data-bind="foreach: TermGroups">
        <div>
            <div class="language-box" data-bind="text: Language.Title"></div>
            <!-- ko foreach: Terms -->

                <!-- markup removed for brevity -->

            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of foreach: TermGroups -->
</div> <!-- end of foreach: Concepts -->
```

It's that innermost `foreach: Terms` that I'm adding to, and which isn't updating.

As for a JsFiddle, I feared that someone would ask for this. If the above edit still doesn't help then I'll try to put one together, but it would be quite removed from my actual work-in-progress and therefore may not be a true likeness.

Comment: At a glance I don't spot any problems in the code you posted. Perhaps it would help to include the relevant View code? Of course, what would be perfect for us to help you is a repro (e.g. a jsfiddle).

Comment: A simplified fiddle would be very helpful. Agree with Jeroen, it doesn't seem like anything is wrong. Then again, would like to see vmTermGroup and vmTerm too. Also, just to point out, way too many for loops. You can use ko.utils.arrayFirst to pick the first item that matches your condition and don't have to loop through things. A simplified fiddle would help you break it down and see any logic holes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a different approach to this problem: Instead of using jQuery to attach events, then looping through the view-model to find the required inner view-model, I added event-binding to my Knockout templates and used these to call the functions inside the context view-model.

Which is arguably what I should have been doing from the start.